# When using an electric brew kettle

Tags: fermentation

Is it good practice to let your Wort cool overnight, then pitch your yeast in the morning. I have heard, there are 2 schools of thought that might affect the taste of the beer.  Also, could contaminate the beer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your sanitation practices are solid and you do not leave the wort uncovered overnight, you should not have a contamination issue.

Regarding the effect of delayed pitch, there is a homebrew scale experiment: http://brulosophy.com/2019/01/07/the-impact-of-delaying-yeast-pitch-exbeeriment-results.
While obviously the sample size is small, the data seems to indicate that if not for contamination, you should not have a real difference in taste.